Postgres Replication Stuck/Reversing?
I'm looking at our replication in Postgres. We have both logical and binary going on. I do a select * from pg_stat_replication order by state; and look at the sent/write/flush/replay lsn values. They look like 31855/17CB26A8 and the values advance over time.
To get the current position, I do a select pg_current_wal_lsn(); and it's at 319E1/73CDD590.
My problem is, as the values advance, they almost reach the current position and then "roll over" and start over again. Is this normal?
I am on v13.10.

Which of the 5 values you mentioned is rolling over, and what does it roll over to?

The lower numbers, like send roll over and they roll over to a much lower value than before.

I had a problem that the wal_receiver_timeout was too low. I set it to 0 on the slaves.
